# Is there a way to search for questions I haven't read?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I would like to set myself some goals of reading all the questions that meet a certain criteria.

E.g. I want to read all the questions for tag X, that have more than Y votes.

A specific example: All questions tagged [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) with more than 200 votes: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+is%3Aquestion+votes%3A200

What I would like is a way of tracking which ones I have not already read.

The best way I can think of at the moment is to favorite a question after having read it, then having "-favorite:true" in the query (note that "favorite:false" doesn't appear to work in queries). Then I get notified about future activity on that question, which I'm not really interested in, plus then I'll have favorite a lot of questions eventually.

Can anyone offer any additional advice on how to do what I would like?

Comment: In other words no.

Answer (score 2):

Using current features in [advanced search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), the closest thing would be is the created: filter

> Dates
> You can use specific dates or date ranges to narrow results down to posts created or active within a certain time period, using the following operators:
>
> created: to specify when the posts were created
> lastactive: for posts active in a specified time period
> Dates can be entered in the following formats:
>
> Absolute dates:
>
> year only – e.g., created:2012..2013 searches posts created from January 1, 2012 through December 31, 2013; created:2012 searches posts created from January 1, 2012 through December 31, 2012.
> year and month – e.g., created:2012-04..2012-05 searches posts created between April 1, 2012 and May 31, 2012.
> day, month, and year – e.g., lastactive:2012-04-03 searches posts who were last active between 12:00 AM on April 3, 2012 and 11:59 PM on April 3, 2012.
>
> Relative dates:
>
> 1y, 1m, and 1d are shorthand for "last year", "last month", and "yesterday" - e.g., if today is April 15, created:1m searches posts created between March 1 and March 31. (You can substitute any number for 1 to look back that many years, months, or days.)
>
> Relative dates in a range (1y..) look back to the same date in the previous period - e.g., if you want to see all the posts active in the last three months, use lastactive:3m.. On April 15, that will show posts from January 15 up to the most recently active. You can close the range as well: lastactive:3m..1m.
>
> Please note that all times are recorded in UTC; the results may not match your timezone.

Sort results by newest, scroll to the bottom, jump to the last page, and start working your way from end to start.

You will need to either need to use the range feature and work your way through the questions by time block, or write down the date of the last question you read and set that as the filter next time you revisit. (Or go to the last question in your history if you forgot/lost that date)